# Location of preferences files

Tags: java, eclipse, preferences

Is it possible to get the location of this directory in eclipse

C:\workspace\metadata\plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\settings

Thanks

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/286538). Please state what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to get the location of .settings directory programatically

Comment: Why do you want to get this location programmatically? You should be using the preference APIs to access this.

Comment: Actually I have a table in my preference page and when I remove an item from the table I want to remove that entry from the preference file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to access the preference settings file directly in order to remove an entry.

Use

```
prefStore.setToDefault("key");
```

to remove the entry.

Comment: This will set to the default value I dont want to keep that in the preference file at all once it is removed from the table

Comment: Default values are not stored in the preference file. They come from the preferences intializer if there is one or a fixed value if there isn't an initializer.

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers that solve your problems